# Moving windows to another disk

Tags: windows, windows-11, sd-card, nvme

I have a laptop that came with windows 11 home. The internal drive is 238.47GB nvme. It has 4 partitions, `EFI`, `microsoft reserved`, `C drive`, and `windows recovery`. I would like to move this windows installation to an external sd card that is 238.30GB in size. If I created the exact same partition layout in this sd card, with the C partition being 0.17GB smaller to account for size difference, and copied all the partitions to the sd card (doing a files copy for the C drive and bitwise copy for the other partitions), will that properly move the operating system to the new sd card? Is there anything else that I might have to take care of?

Comment: Windows can't boot from external storage

Comment: To clarify what @gronostaj has indicated, a stand-alone installation of Windows cannot boot from that type of storage device.  Windows to Go could in theory, but the performance would be so bad it would drive you crazy. Why don't you just replace the NVMe drive with a larger disk?  There is no way to accomplish what you want, an "Sd card" performance would be so bad, it won't accomplish your goal.

Comment: @Ramhound I wanted to do that so that I could have linux on the internal drive (need it for work, windows is for gaming). I guess I could reduce windows partition size and dual boot Linux. What is the minimum windows C drive size? Will 38.47GB be enough?

Comment: The system requirements for Windows are well documented on Microsoft's website

Comment: I'd say you realistically need at least 80 GB to run Windows without running into problems with Windows Update being stuck due to low disk space etc. and for version updates you'll probably need more.